# What can I put a tree control inside to allow vertical scroll bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, scrollbar

I have a treeview control that extends way past the bottom of the screen.  What do you recommend to put the treeview control into that will allow it to have a vertical scrollbar to allow the treeview control to load in that and not extend the screen super far down the page?

Comment: A `div` with `overflow: scroll;`? or maybe even with CSS3's `overflow-y:scroll;`

Comment: you are correct! That worked.  Can you post it as an answer and I will accept it as one.  Thanks